# Setting custom header on each page of an excel sheet using xlsxwriter

Tags: header, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to set custom header on each page within the same sheet in excel using xlsxwriter?

Here I get two pages, but the same header on each. So this just sets for the entire sheet.

```
import xlsxwriter

data = ["a", "b", "c"]
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

for index,d in enumerate(data):
    ws.write(index,0,d)
    ws.print_area(index,0,index,10)
    ws.set_header("&C Header %s"%d)
    ws.set_h_pagebreaks([index])                                         
ws.set_page_view()
wb.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in Excel?

Comment: No...  you are right, that is sort of prerequisite. xlsxwriter is great though, thanks.